# GitHub Pages: cannot bundle exec jekyll serve on OS X

Tags: macos, rubygems, bundler, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to get a default installation of Jekyll for GitHub Pages installed.
I am mostly following the [documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/).

I have Homebrew installed, which I used to install ruby.

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

My repository already has a `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

So I try to install the dependencies.
I am prompted to install to `vendor/bundle`, so I do.

```
$ bundle install --path vendor/bundle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing RedCloth 4.2.9 with native extensions
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
Installing minitest 5.8.3
Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
Installing addressable 2.3.8
Installing blankslate 2.1.2.4
Installing fast-stemmer 1.0.2 with native extensions
Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Installing execjs 2.6.0
Installing colorator 0.1
Installing ffi 1.9.10 with native extensions
Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
Installing gemoji 2.1.0
Installing net-dns 0.8.0
Installing public_suffix 1.5.2
Installing jekyll-paginate 1.1.0
Installing sass 3.4.20
Installing rb-fsevent 0.9.6
Installing kramdown 1.9.0
Installing liquid 2.6.2
Installing mercenary 0.3.5
Installing posix-spawn 0.3.11 with native extensions
Installing yajl-ruby 1.2.1 with native extensions
Installing redcarpet 3.3.3 with native extensions
Installing safe_yaml 1.0.4
Installing jekyll-feed 0.3.1
Installing mini_portile2 2.0.0
Installing jekyll-sitemap 0.9.0
Installing maruku 0.7.0
Installing rdiscount 2.1.8 with native extensions
Installing terminal-table 1.5.2
Using bundler 1.11.2
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing parslet 1.5.0
Installing classifier-reborn 2.0.4
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing ethon 0.8.0
Installing rb-inotify 0.9.5
Installing faraday 0.9.2
Installing jekyll-sass-converter 1.3.0
Installing pygments.rb 0.6.3
Installing nokogiri 1.6.7 with native extensions
Installing activesupport 4.2.5
Installing toml 0.1.2
Installing jekyll-coffeescript 1.0.1
Installing typhoeus 0.8.0
Installing listen 3.0.5
Installing sawyer 0.6.0
Installing html-pipeline 1.9.0
Installing github-pages-health-check 0.5.3
Installing jekyll-watch 1.3.0
Installing octokit 4.2.0
Installing jekyll-gist 1.4.0
Installing jekyll 2.4.0
Installing jekyll-mentions 0.2.1
Installing jekyll-redirect-from 0.8.0
Installing jemoji 0.5.0
Installing github-pages 40
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 59 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
Post-install message from html-pipeline:
-------------------------------------------------
Thank you for installing html-pipeline!
You must bundle Filter gem dependencies.
See html-pipeline README.md for more details.
https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline#dependencies
-------------------------------------------------
```

Everything should work now, right?

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Could not find RedCloth-4.2.9 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I guess not, and I am not sure why.

The list of installed bundles seems right...

```
$ bundle list
Gems included by the bundle:
  * RedCloth (4.2.9)
  * activesupport (4.2.5)
  * addressable (2.3.8)
  * blankslate (2.1.2.4)
  * bundler (1.11.2)
  * classifier-reborn (2.0.4)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
  * colorator (0.1)
  * ethon (0.8.0)
  * execjs (2.6.0)
  * faraday (0.9.2)
  * fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
  * ffi (1.9.10)
  * gemoji (2.1.0)
  * github-pages (40)
  * github-pages-health-check (0.5.3)
  * html-pipeline (1.9.0)
  * i18n (0.7.0)
  * jekyll (2.4.0)
  * jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
  * jekyll-feed (0.3.1)
  * jekyll-gist (1.4.0)
  * jekyll-mentions (0.2.1)
  * jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
  * jekyll-redirect-from (0.8.0)
  * jekyll-sass-converter (1.3.0)
  * jekyll-sitemap (0.9.0)
  * jekyll-watch (1.3.0)
  * jemoji (0.5.0)
  * json (1.8.3)
  * kramdown (1.9.0)
  * liquid (2.6.2)
  * listen (3.0.5)
  * maruku (0.7.0)
  * mercenary (0.3.5)
  * mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
  * minitest (5.8.3)
  * multipart-post (2.0.0)
  * net-dns (0.8.0)
  * nokogiri (1.6.7)
  * octokit (4.2.0)
  * parslet (1.5.0)
  * posix-spawn (0.3.11)
  * public_suffix (1.5.2)
  * pygments.rb (0.6.3)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.6)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.5)
  * rdiscount (2.1.8)
  * redcarpet (3.3.3)
  * safe_yaml (1.0.4)
  * sass (3.4.20)
  * sawyer (0.6.0)
  * terminal-table (1.5.2)
  * thread_safe (0.3.5)
  * toml (0.1.2)
  * typhoeus (0.8.0)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * yajl-ruby (1.2.1)
```

I found online in some other questions that my `GEM_PATH` might be incorrect, which seems plausible, since my `GEM_PATH` is empty.
What should I set it to be, if anything?

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot?